# Is abundance of chemical elements in the asteroid belt / solar system real through higher concentrations?

Tags: mining, chemistry

Given humanity would be once able to access any minerals in the asteroid belt and moons of planets, would be there some chemical elements (if stable isotopes exist) still considered as [rare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rare-earth_element)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "real" or "once", and I'm not totally sure what you mean by "rare", but the platinum, iridium, and other precious metals in asteroids probably count.

Comment: A link to the Wikipedia page on Rare Earth Elements was added in an edit, which if relevant would make the answer easy. However, I don't think that it is relevant due to a much more natural connection between the words "rare" and "abundance". Are you asking whether any elements would be classified as "Rare Earth Elements" if a new source becomes available and makes those elements abundant?

Comment: Yes though i.e. wolfram is yet rarer but not classified as such, so question relies to "rare and rarer but (in case)  stable isotopes"